# Insert in MYSQL multiple rows with one common value

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to do a select from one table and insert the return values into another table with a common value representing the search parameter using the insert/select function.  For simplicities sake instead of...

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b) VALUES (1,1,1), (4,5,6);
```

I want to do something like this....

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b) VALUES (1), (4,5,6);
```

Except where the second column b has several hundred values and 'a' is the common value.  I've tried using SET for 'a' but either this can't be done or I can't get the syntax correct.  The reason I'm doing this is to avoid building up an insert function in PHP.  Here is the best I have....

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name 
  (a,b) 
SET a = '1' 
SELECT c 
  FROM tbl_name2 
 WHERE `d` LIKE '%word%'
```

Comment: Post [your own answer as an answer below](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12513/should-i-not-answer-my-own-questions), then mark it as accepted by clicking the checkmark.

Comment: Guess I have to wait 8 hours to self answer.

Comment: I didn't know that.  In that case, you can roll back your edit to restore your answer if you wish.  Otherwise, someone else will almost certainly answer within a few minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I FIGURED IT OUT, already typed all of this, might as well post the answer for everyone.

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name
  (a,b) 
SELECT "2", c 
  FROM tbl_name2 
 WHERE d LIKE '%word%'
```

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing the point, but doing:

`INSERT INTO tbl_name (a,b) (SELECT 1,c FROM tbl_name2 WHERE d like '%word%';);`

will do the job.